# Printing a subclass string

Tags: class, subclass, python-3.3, superclass

I have a "Superclass" and a "subclass"

```
class Triangle(GeoMetricObject):
  def __init__(self,side1=1,side2=1,side3=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.__side1= side1
        self.__side2= side2
        self.__side3= side3
  def getPerimeter(self,side1,side2,side3):
        return side1+side2+side3
  def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()+"side1:"+(self.__side1)+"side2:"+(self.__side2)+"side3:"+(self.__side3)
```

from GeometricObject import GeoMetricObject,Triangle

The second file , which runs the modules above.

```
def main():
s1= int(input("What is the length  of the first side? "))
s2= int(input("What is the length  of the second side? "))
s3= int(input("What is the length  of the third side? "))
side1=s1
side2=s2
side3=s3
t1 = Triangle(s1,s2,s3)
l = GeoMetricObject()
print("Default color of Triangle:",l.getColor())
print("The Perimeter of Triangle : ",t1.getPerimeter(side1,side2,side3,))
print(Triangle())
```

main()

My problem is that I can seem to get the proper output from the subclass **str** properly. It gives me this error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 15, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 14, in main
File "c:\Users\Fergus\Desktop\GeometricObject.py", line 26, in __str__
return super().__str__()+"side1:"+(self.__side1)+"side2:"+(self.__side2)+"side3:"+(self.__side3)
builtins.TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

I am not sure how to fix this problem. I not a very good programmer , mostly a biologist.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert implictly int to string when you do your addition. You can't do an addition between these different types. However, if you convert your ints to string, no problem

replace this:

```
super().__str__()+"side1:"+(self.__side1)+"side2:"+(self.__side2)+"side3:"+(self.__side3)
```

by this:

```
super().__str__()+"side1:"+str(self.__side1)+"side2:"+str(self.__side2)+"side3:"+str(self.__side3)
```

Don't have python3 to check but it should work.

Comment: Thanks !  I thought it couldnt be converted since the sides were technically ints, but I guess that condition dosent need to be satisfied if it is just printed as output.